# Angular filter data from html

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple list that i would like to filter.

Example code:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data"></div>
```

example data:

```
  data = [
        {
         "img" : "assets/img/photos/05.jpg",
         "title" : "Denim Jeans",
         "overview": "today"    
        },
        {
         "img" : "assets/img/photos/05.jpg",
         "title" : "Denim jacket",
         "overview": "month"

        },
];
```

I want to show only which have `overview` field `month`.

I expected something like this:

```
*ngFor = "let x of data == overview"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of data">
  <div *ngIf="x.overview === 'month'">
    <p>{{ x.title }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

The `ng-container` is just a logical construct that allows you to add conditions/loops/etc without them having a structural element on the page.

So, in your case the container loops though everything in the array and the inner div determines if the div appears due to the check on the `x.overview` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom pipe to filter data like below

```
<div *ngFor="let x of (data | overviewMonth)">
   {{x}}
</div>



import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';



@Pipe({ name: 'overviewMonth' })
export class overviewMonthsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(alloverViews: data[]) {
  return alloverViews.filter(x => x.overview === 'month');
 }
}
```

Refer https://angular.io/guide/pipes